# How can I add dynamic alias for columns while using UNPIVOT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I am trying to get total sales per day for the last 7 days. Instead of using Day1, Day2 etc I would like to get actual date in column names. How can I make this dynamic? Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

```
DECLARE @Today AS DATETIME = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)

SELECT SUMTYPE AS [Type],
    SUMTOTAL AS [Totals]
FROM (
    SELECT (
            SELECT count(id)
            FROM sales
            WHERE datediff(DAY, CAST(createdTimestamp AS DATE), @Today) = 0
            ) AS Day1,
        (   SELECT count(id)
            FROM sales
            WHERE datediff(DAY, CAST(createdTimestamp AS DATE), @Today) = 1
            ) AS Day2,
        (   SELECT count(id)
            FROM sales
            WHERE datediff(DAY, CAST(createdTimestamp AS DATE), @Today) = 2
            ) AS Day3,
        (   SELECT count(id)
            FROM sales
            WHERE datediff(DAY, CAST(createdTimestamp AS DATE), @Today) = 3
            ) AS Day4,
        (   SELECT count(id)
            FROM sales
            WHERE datediff(DAY, CAST(createdTimestamp AS DATE), @Today) = 4
            ) AS Day5,
        (   SELECT count(id)
            FROM sales
            WHERE datediff(DAY, CAST(createdTimestamp AS DATE), @Today) = 5
            ) AS Day6,
        (   SELECT count(id)
            FROM sales
            WHERE datediff(DAY, CAST(createdTimestamp AS DATE), @Today) = 6
            ) AS Day7
    ) b
UNPIVOT(SUMTOTAL FOR SUMTYPE IN (
      [Day1], [Day2], [Day3], [Day4], [Day5], [Day6], [Day7])
     ) AS UNPVT;
```

Comment: Is it really necessary? SQL doesn't do well with dynamic column names. Also what version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: You will need to use [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for dynamic query

Comment: Unpivot usually results in fewer columns. Dynamic headings us more common for a Pivot.

Comment: Have you tried looking for previous answers on how to do dynamic pivots? There are quite a few of those every week

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without `UNPIVOT` and dynamic T-SQL statement.

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [TypeID]  
          ,[Type] 
    FROM 
    (
        VALUES (0, 'Day1')
              ,(1, 'Day2')
              ,(2, 'Day3')
              ,(3, 'Day4')
              ,(4, 'Day5')
              ,(5, 'Day6')
              ,(6, 'Day7')
    ) DS ([TypeID],  [Type])
) 
SELECT DS.[Type]
      ,COUNT(id) AS [Totals]
FROM DataSource DS
LEFT JOIN #sales S
    ON DS.[TypeID] = DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(S.createdTimestamp AS DATE), @Today) 
GROUP BY DS.[Type];
```

Here is the full working example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #sales;

-- Create a sample sales table
CREATE TABLE #sales (
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    createdTimestamp DATETIME
);

-- Insert sample data into the sales table
INSERT INTO #sales (createdTimestamp) VALUES
    (GETDATE()),
    (DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())),
    (DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())),
    (DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())),
    (DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())),
    (DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE())),
    (DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE())),
    (DATEADD(DAY, -4, GETDATE())),
    (DATEADD(DAY, -4, GETDATE())),
    (DATEADD(DAY, -6, GETDATE()));

-- Declare @Today variable and set its value
DECLARE @Today AS DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0);

-- Generate the sample sales table
SELECT SUMTYPE AS [Type], SUMTOTAL AS [Totals]
FROM (
    SELECT
        (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM #sales WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(createdTimestamp AS DATE), @Today) = 0) AS Day1,
        (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM #sales WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(createdTimestamp AS DATE), @Today) = 1) AS Day2,
        (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM #sales WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(createdTimestamp AS DATE), @Today) = 2) AS Day3,
        (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM #sales WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(createdTimestamp AS DATE), @Today) = 3) AS Day4,
        (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM #sales WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(createdTimestamp AS DATE), @Today) = 4) AS Day5,
        (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM #sales WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(createdTimestamp AS DATE), @Today) = 5) AS Day6,
        (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM #sales WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(createdTimestamp AS DATE), @Today) = 6) AS Day7
) b
UNPIVOT (
    SUMTOTAL FOR SUMTYPE IN ([Day1], [Day2], [Day3], [Day4], [Day5], [Day6], [Day7]) 
) AS UNPVT;

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [TypeID]  
          ,[Type] 
    FROM 
    (
        VALUES (0, 'Day1')
              ,(1, 'Day2')
              ,(2, 'Day3')
              ,(3, 'Day4')
              ,(4, 'Day5')
              ,(5, 'Day6')
              ,(6, 'Day7')
    ) DS ([TypeID],  [Type])
) 
SELECT DS.[Type]
      ,COUNT(id) AS [Totals]
FROM DataSource DS
LEFT JOIN #sales S
    ON DS.[TypeID] = DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(S.createdTimestamp AS DATE), @Today) 
GROUP BY DS.[Type];
```

[image]

Comment: This does not address the inefficiency of running 7 independent queries when 1 is possible. Consider use of "conditional aggregates" instead. Plus, don't alter every row of data (multiple times) using functions to suit the filter.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell show me how it should be done, sir :-)

Comment: I think @PaulMaxwell means something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/I6GO-gtM

Comment: @PaulMaxwell I have never edit the answer.

Comment: Sorry! Please forgive me I got myself confused. Nevertheless this is what I had in mind when I made the initial comment:  https://dbfiddle.uk/I6GO-gtM  which uses conditional aggregates. I will delete the erroneous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You refer to UNPIVOT in your question title, so my assumption is that you want the counts of daily sales as a column. So, instead of multiple dynamic column headings that you unpivot, why not just use dates (formatted to suit your preference) as another column? This way you do not need dynamic SQL at all.

```
DECLARE @Today AS DATETIME = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0);

WITH ranges as (
    SELECT dayno, from_dt, to_dt
    FROM (
        VALUES (1,                   @Today ,dateadd(day,   1, @Today))
              ,(2, dateadd(day, - 1, @today),                  @Today)
              ,(3, dateadd(day, - 2, @today),dateadd(day, - 1, @today))
              ,(4, dateadd(day, - 3, @today),dateadd(day, - 2, @today))
              ,(5, dateadd(day, - 4, @today),dateadd(day, - 3, @today))
              ,(6, dateadd(day, - 5, @today),dateadd(day, - 4, @today))
              ,(7, dateadd(day, - 6, @today),dateadd(day, - 5, @today))
         ) r (dayno, from_dt, to_dt)
   )
SELECT
     convert(varchar(10),r.from_dt,120) as day_label /* change 120 to preferred style */
   , COUNT(s.id) as Totals
FROM ranges r
LEFT JOIN sales s
    ON  s.createdTimestamp >= r.from_dt and s.createdTimestamp < r.to_dt
GROUP BY
  r.from_dt
ORDER BY
  r.from_dt DESC
```

The result looks like this:

| day_label | Totals |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-07-16 | 1 |
| 2023-07-15 | 4 |
| 2023-07-14 | 1 |
| 2023-07-13 | 1 |
| 2023-07-12 | 2 |
| 2023-07-11 | 0 |
| 2023-07-10 | 1 |

Please also note that instead of converting every row of your data using `datediff` (which results in integers) this query uses dates so if you have an index on sales.createdTimestamp this query should make full use of it.

See this demonstrated at this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1En_nlW4)

Kudos to Charliefeace for proposing the use of `values(...)` to substitute for unpivot.